# How to set default page dimension in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying converting my Photoshop design into a web site, manually writing HTML and CSS. It's my first time doing this type of exercise, so I'm having a little problem from the get-go with page dimensions.

I did my PS design using a 1920px page width, this is the fullscreen [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLIw.jpg). Writing CSS, I set header width to 1920px and logo width to 150px (as in the PS file). But I obtain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVmLY.jpg) (don't worry about logo position).

As you can see, the page is very "zoomed in" and the scrollbar appears down below. I want to display the whole page without a scrollbar, just as in PS, keeping the same ratio between elements.

This is my HTML & CSS code for the header:

```css
#logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  /* I also tried width: 100% */
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="..\codice\export\logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

As shown in the code, I also tried setting the header's width to 100% but this way the logo proportion (150 px / 1920 px) was not respected.

How can I write in CSS: "1920 should be your 100% when visualizing the page with the browser"?

I'm sorry if this is a silly question but it's my first time working with these tools.

Comment: Can you enter `innerWidth` or `devicePixelRatio` on the console (on Developer Tools) and share the result?

Comment: I wrote `devicePixelRatio` on the console on Chrome's Developer Tools and I got "1.25". What does it means?

Comment: You should press F12 while the browser is open. A window with the name "Developer Tools" should open. Check the tabs at the top and click on "Console". You should write them there.

Comment: I got `innerWidth` 598 and `devicePixelRatio` 1.25

Comment: I guess  `devicePixelRatio ` should be 1. How can I set it using CSS? I tried with the meta tag viewport but without success.

Comment: You said that your Photoshop design is 1920px wide, so I assumed your screen width as 1920px. Is that the case? If it is, your `devicePixelRatio` returned `1.25`. This suggests that while your screen is 1920px wide, your OS is using %125 scale on the display. You're seeing everything bigger, and the window/viewport width inside the browser is (should be) `1536` (1920/1.25). Your image won't fit in that area. To keep the image inside the viewport (make it full width), you'd have to apply `width: 100%` on the image.

Comment: Yes that's it! Is there a way for me to set in CSS something like "if devicePixelRatio is > 1, visualize the webpage as devicePixelRatio =1"?

Comment: There's not a definite answer to that. You could use CSS `zoom` property, but I'd advise against it. This would break the site. For example, when you zoom on a page, `devicePixelRatio` changes accordingly. If you want your image to be full width, you should simply use `width: 100%`. The image will cover the screen no matter what the screen width is.

Comment: I don't know why I kept saying image. I meant your `#header` element :) Also, the real problem is with your OS display scale. If you want it to look small, just disable the scale on your display. You shouldn't be forcing the visitor into viewing the site at some specific dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1dyeohm/5/)

You can check with a fluid `width: 100%` you should not have this horizontally scrollbar

Then i added a `header_content` div with a fixed width of 520px (then you can see it is centered and well placed. but you will need to change that value according to your photoshop header width.

Note : css `margin:0 auto` makes your div centered horizontally.

[image]

Comment: But using `width: 100%` the logo appears much bigger than it should (see my two imgur links in the post for reference)

Comment: Yes check my new jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j1dyeohm/5/ you must add a children div

Comment: Using your new code I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/R4wRkkI): there still is a scrollbar, and a white space appears next to the header.

Comment: White space around your header is coming from your body  , try with that css :`body {padding:0;margin:0}`

About the scroll bar , are you sure your photoshop template for the central part is 1920 px ? Your header width must be around 1000px or 1250px i guess

Comment: The last image I posted has `body: {padding:0;margin:0}`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code ?  then i can  help you with more ease

Comment: Ok so [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zek93jhw/3/) is the starting point: the logo should be 150px on a 1920px header (so about 7% of the header).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: the logo is [much bigger](https://imgur.com/a/PT96Xpu) than it should be.

The 150 px logo should be very small compared to the 1920px header.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional HTML and CSS may solve the problem for you! And I'm considering you have to add the `menu` which you not yet done.  Here is my solution. I put some helpful comment that you help you to understand the code properly. You can have same code at my [codepen](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/eapgKz) example.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  /* if you don't add  this your code will be hidden under the #heade */
}

#logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*No need to add 'px' when the value is 0 */
  left: 0;
  /* I also tried width: 100% */
  right: 0;
  /*Thsi will cover the right side. So no need to declear a width*/
  /* logo has some space at to so we are adding a padding at top*/
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 75px;
  /* reduce to 75px so header will be just half of the logo image*/
  background: #000000;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  /* hae to make this responsive for smallar devices*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
  float: right
}


/*Eacaping the  proper code for the navigation so here is some face code */

.navigation {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="http://www.logospng.com/images/22/itunes-12-logopng-wikimedia-commons-22786.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
      Home Link1 link2 ecc
      <!-- I escaping the coding of nav here -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: the logo is [much bigger](https://imgur.com/a/PT96Xpu) than it should be.

The 150 px logo should be very small compared to the 1920px header.

Comment: OK!  What is you PSD logo Size? If it's larger then adjust the `#logo img ` & `#header`'s  value according it. No big deal!

Comment: I have to respect 1920px header width and 150px logo width, can't change dimensions.

Comment: My code has also 150px logo with 1920px header! Though my logo image is much bigger than 150px but will resized to` width: 150px;   height: 150px;'